# Determine the line count of a specific line from a text file in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to get the count of a specific line in .NET. Currently I have been using the below code:-

```
Do While sr.Peek >= 1
               sr.ReadLine()
               NumberOfLines += 1
           Loop
```

Is there any other way to do this as I want to avoid looping.

Comment: Please clarify what do you actually need. Is it a Row number of certain line, if so what are the criteria to find that line ?

Comment: No. You have to loop to read multiple lines. What's the problem with looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the position in the file you can do this:

```
Dim pos As Integer = 10
Dim subStr As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\path\\x.txt").Substring(0, pos)
Dim lineNo As Integer = subStr.Split(vbCrLf).Count
```

If you don't have the position but you have the content of your line you can do the below. Note that if there are lines looking the same you will always find the first line.

```
Dim content As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\...\\x.txt")
Dim pos As Integer = content.IndexOf("<<the content of your line goes here>>")
Dim lineNo As Integer = content.Substring(0, pos).Split(vbCrLf).Count
```

To get total line count in a file:

```
Dim lines As Integer = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\...path...\\x.txt").Length
```

Comment: This is used to determine the total no. of lines in the text file. I want to find the line no of a specific line.

Comment: @Aditi, do you wish to seek specific line ? If so then by what ?